# How to efficiently calculate the outer product of two series of matrices in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Lets say I have A(KxMxN) and B(KxLxN) matrices, where L,M,N are small and K is a large number. I would like to calculate the outer product of using the last 2 dimensions along the 1st dimension to get matrix C(KxMxL).

I can do this by running a for loop for each index *k* in "K" and use numpy's matmul function for 2D matrices

```
out = [np.matmul(x,y.T) for x, y in zip(A, B)]
out=np.asarray(out)
```

I wonder if I can do it without the for loop/comprehension as K is a very large number.

Comment: It's really an inner product - over a set of subarrays.  Outer product increases the dimensions, and doesn't sum any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `A` has shape `(K, M, N)` and `B` has shape `(K, L, N)`, and you wish to find the sum of products with shape `(K, M, L)`, you could use `np.einsum`:

```
C = np.einsum('kmn,kln->kml', A, B)
```

Answer (score 0):

`matmul` works, with a transpose in `B`, so its 2nd to last dim matches the last of `A`.

```
In [1019]: A=np.random.rand(K,M,N)
In [1021]: B=np.random.rand(K,L,N)

In [1023]: C=np.einsum('kmn,kln->kml',A,B)
In [1024]: C.shape
Out[1024]: (2, 4, 3)

In [1026]: D=A@B.transpose(0,2,1)
In [1027]: D.shape
Out[1027]: (2, 4, 3)

In [1028]: np.allclose(C,D)
Out[1028]: True
```

For this small example the `timeit` is the same.

`[np.dot(x,y.T) for x, y in zip(A, B)]` does the same thing; match the 2nd last dim of `y` with that of `x`, and iterate on the 1st dim of `A` and `B`.